# return whole object with updated arrays in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, immutable.js

I am having problem in showing the features object with updated features array inside it. For untouched/undeleted part, its working fine but the feature which I delete returns only the features
array instead of showing whole object with features array inside it. What I mean is, if I have an object like this

```
0: Object
feature_description: "Room Amenities"
feature_type: "roomamenities"
features:Array(6)
_id:"59395255455a5b043c764a29"

1:Object
feature_name: "Room Amenities"
feature_type: "bathroom"
features:Array(3)
_id:"59395255455a5b043c764a29"
```

Now that When I delete the feature of roomamenities feature type, I get the following result

```
0:Object
features: Array(5) # 5 not 6 because one item is deleted 

1:Object
feature_name: "Room Amenities"
feature_type: "bathroom"
features:Array(3)
_id:"59395255455a5b043c764a29"
```

instead it should return the following object

```
0: Object
feature_description: "Room Amenities"
feature_type: "roomamenities"
features:Array(5)
_id:"59395255455a5b043c764a29"

1:Object
feature_name: "Room Amenities"
feature_type: "bathroom"
features:Array(3)
_id:"59395255455a5b043c764a29"
```

How can I resolve my issue?

Here is my code of reducer

```
case UPDATE_REQUESTED_FEATURES_SUCCESS:
  return state
    .update("features", features =>
      state.get('features').map(feature => {
        console.log("feature", feature);
        if (feature.get("feature_type") === "roomamenities") {
          return {
            ...feature,
            features: feature.get("features").map(subFeature => {
              return subFeature.get("_id") !== action.response.data._id;
            })
          };
        } else {
          return feature;
        }
      })
    );
```

This is the result of features object yielded from reducers by consoling state.get('features')

[image]

Comment: Could you please show us the data structure in code instead of what the console shows you ?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand what data structure you are talking about.

Comment: In the first part your are talking about an object but you show us `0: Object [...] 1: Object [...]` - This seems to be an array not an object. Please show us the data structure in JS Array or object format

Comment: For example: An object can be shown like `{id: "123", text: "Test"}` and an array like `["a1", "a2"]`

Comment: @Weedoze I have udpated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `feature` objects are ImmutableJS Maps. So replace this:

```
  return {
    ...feature,
    features: feature.get("features").map(subFeature => {
      return subFeature.get("_id") !== action.response.data._id;
    })
  };
```

with:

```
  return feature.set("features", 
      feature.get("features").filter(subFeature => {
          return subFeature.get("_id") !== action.response.data._id;
      })
  );
```

Comment: How does this remove the selected item? I will try this and will let you know

Comment: In fact there is another thing to correct: your inner `.map` call should be a `.filter`. I updated it just now.

Comment: This one worked but is the reason of my code not working is just because of the use of spread operator?

Comment: Yes, the spread operator lists enumerable properties, and ImmatableJS does not expose them as such.